# JSON.Parse and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject failes

Tags: json, json.net, deserialization

5 for deserializing my JSON object that I get over Restful url.

Here are the two method i tried to deserialize

```
  var retObject1 = JObject.Parse(_strResponse);
  var rootObject2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductObjLibrary>>(_strResponse);
```

my string response is as below

```
{"GetProductsResult":[{"BrandID":19081,"BrandName":"A1C NOW SELFCHECK SYSTEM","BrandNameHTML":"A1C NOW SELFCHECK SYSTEM","ClassName":"Diabetes","CleanProductURL":"a1c_now_selfcheck_system","GenericName":"blood glucose monitoring","ManufacturerName":"Bayer","ProductID":19081,"ProductName":"A1C NOW SELFCHECK SYSTEM","Rank":0},{"BrandID":19045,"BrandName":"ABILIFY","BrandNameHTML":"ABILIFY","ClassName":"Antipsychotic","CleanProductURL":"abilify","GenericName":"aripiprazole","ManufacturerName":"Bristol-Myers Squibb and Otsuka","ProductID":19045,"ProductName":"ABILIFY","Rank":0},{"BrandID":19995,"BrandName":"ABRAXANE","BrandNameHTML":"ABRAXANE","ClassName":"Oncology: Breast Cancer","CleanProductURL":"abraxane","GenericName":"paclitaxel","ManufacturerName":"Abraxis Oncology","ProductID":19995,"ProductName":"ABRAXANE","Rank":0},{"BrandID":18413,"BrandName":"ACCOLATE","BrandNameHTML":"ACCOLATE","ClassName":"Asthma\/COPD","CleanProductURL":"accolate","GenericName":"zafirlukast","ManufacturerName":"AstraZeneca Pharmaceuticals","ProductID":18413,"ProductName":"ACCOLATE","Rank":0},{"BrandID":19595,"BrandName":"ACCU-CHECK SPIRIT INSULIN PUMP","BrandNameHTML":"ACCU-CHECK SPIRIT INSULIN PUMP","ClassName":"Diabetes","CleanProductURL":"accu_check_spirit_insulin_pump","GenericName":"blood glucose monitoring","ManufacturerName":"Roche","ProductID":19595,"ProductName":"ACCU-CHECK SPIRIT INSULIN PUMP","Rank":0}]}
```

After I convert this string using first method retObject1 i get below object

```
{
  "GetProductsResult": [
    {
      "BrandID": 19081,
      "BrandName": "A1C NOW SELFCHECK SYSTEM",
      "BrandNameHTML": "A1C NOW SELFCHECK SYSTEM",
      "ClassName": "Diabetes",
      "CleanProductURL": "a1c_now_selfcheck_system",
      "GenericName": "blood glucose monitoring",
      "ManufacturerName": "Bayer",
      "ProductID": 19081,
      "ProductName": "A1C NOW SELFCHECK SYSTEM",
      "Rank": 0
    },
    {
      "BrandID": 19045,
      "BrandName": "ABILIFY",
      "BrandNameHTML": "ABILIFY",
      "ClassName": "Antipsychotic",
      "CleanProductURL": "abilify",
      "GenericName": "aripiprazole",
      "ManufacturerName": "Bristol-Myers Squibb and Otsuka",
      "ProductID": 19045,
      "ProductName": "ABILIFY",
      "Rank": 0
    },
    {
      "BrandID": 19995,
      "BrandName": "ABRAXANE",
      "BrandNameHTML": "ABRAXANE",
      "ClassName": "Oncology: Breast Cancer",
      "CleanProductURL": "abraxane",
      "GenericName": "paclitaxel",
      "ManufacturerName": "Abraxis Oncology",
      "ProductID": 19995,
      "ProductName": "ABRAXANE",
      "Rank": 0
    },
    {
      "BrandID": 18413,
      "BrandName": "ACCOLATE",
      "BrandNameHTML": "ACCOLATE",
      "ClassName": "Asthma/COPD",
      "CleanProductURL": "accolate",
      "GenericName": "zafirlukast",
      "ManufacturerName": "AstraZeneca Pharmaceuticals",
      "ProductID": 18413,
      "ProductName": "ACCOLATE",
      "Rank": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

using second method I get bellow error

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Fredrik Rofors
http://codesurf.blogspot.com/2012/10/jsonconvertdeserializeobject-cannot.html

Lesson learned:

```
If the json value is '[]' => declare the field as List<type>
If the json value is '{}' => declare the field IDictionary<type, type>
```

I handled it like this in my case.

```
 var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, List<ProductObjLibrary>>>(_strResponse);
                       if (rootObject != null)
                           _products = rootObject.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem. Just a suggestion => so that you don't have to worry about json value enclosed in [] or {}. I am using the following code for my json value enclosed in {} but keep in mind, my purpose is to handle any case.

```
 Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(response_result);
```

The above code only works for 1st level or depth, for 2nd level code would be

```
 Dictionary<string, object> values =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object> >>(response_result);
```

and so forth for multi-level

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,**...**>> > >
```

to solve this problem for multi-level is extremely tricky and at the moment, i am gonna be taking a dive into this problem.